# Which are the API's used for Creating autocad Files in Forge.. couldnt get from documentation

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are designing an IOS applications where users can makes simple drawings for boxes and Trays. This will be 2D Drawings.
We shall have the complete information of the each lines, their length intersection etc to be available to use as needed.Please find below a sample of the drawings which we need to export to Autocad format and save.

https://autodesk.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/622485i5D2D6FDBA5029BE1/image-size/medium?v=1.0&px=400

Which are the API's in Forge for us to use to convert this to a DWG or DXF file.

Dear Cyrille,

We were checking the API Docs in https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/ but not able to get the Actual API's to use for this.

We are primarily looking at creating new DWG files using the API's -

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-POST/

Any references/suggestions in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed looking at one of the right endpoints already :)

With our Design Automation service one will need to bring your own .NET AutoCAD plugin and upload it to our service as an AppPackage so it can be called as Activity in a Workitem request.

See the tutorial [here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/tutorials/convert-dwg-to-pdf/) to walk you through the whole process.

And refer to samples below to create your own AutoCAD plugin to draw from inputs:
- https://github.com/Giedrius-Kristinaitis/C-Sharp_AutoCAD_Plugin
- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-.net-custom.activity.sample
- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=autocad&type=&language=